# my site is accessible by ftp://ftp.example.com is it safe?

Tags: ssl, ftp, hosting, protocols, shared-hosting

I just hosted my site www.example.com (lets assume) and my FTP server is ftp.example.com so whenever anyone tries to navigate to ftp://ftp.example.com they are prompted for username n pass to get ftp access , It's kindaa annoying , I am on shared hosting . When I looked on for some other sites like 
housing.co.in or zomato they are not allowing access to ftp://.... protocol of their site . I want same stuff . Any help or clearance is appreciated . Is getting a SSL certificate solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Because those other sites have other ways to connect to the disk of the server to update the content.

It really depends on your provider (and your skill set) to use the other routes. The provider might have given you SSH access so you can use scp or SFTP to update the content. You wouldn't have to expose the FTP protocol then.